# How can I investigate .NET DLL Dependency?

Tags: .net, dll, reflector

I get an exception related to a DLL which can't be loaded but... no project seems to reference that DLL.

How can I know who is calling it?

Comment: Take a look at [Fuslogvw.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) if it is a managed dll or [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) if it is a native dll.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks!!

Comment: jet brains dotPeek

Answer (score -1):

run ildasm from the Visual Studio command prompt.   You will find ildasm in the same folder as Visual Studio (devenv)

With ildasm you can loan an assembly and then disassemble it back to IL.   This isn't really helpful in most cases, but it will also give you access to the manifest for your assembly.
[image]

Double click on the Manifest, and you will get the manifest for that Assembly.   You are interested in the stuff at the top which will be all the assembly references.
[image]

Pull up the manifest for each of the referenced assemblies and you will find the one that has a dependency on the assembly causing problems.